# Get Solvemedia image using RestSharp

Tags: c#, image, http, restsharp

I'm developing an application which needs to make a query on a website to extract certain data, such as the user's name, points / remaining balance etc.

I present a problem in the login, the client needs to solve a captcha solvemedia to be able to enter the website, I would like to extract the image of this captcha and show it to the client but I am having problems to extract it, i'm trying to do it through http requests with RestSharp, the reason I do not do it with a webbrowser or selenium is that it spends a lot more resources.

i try this:

```
RestClient restClient = new RestClient(@"//api-secure.solvemedia.com/papi/media?c=2@gAB09NHSertXLv3TnpobmKDxvkjsaT4m@X4wLMdkN.u0ENU8bgrS3KH9APTC4lJjokJaIfZePPIgNLL84QkOaQlXcxzHvOVTTU98Of7mo8BoC0QQuiH1RMqMrGof6BbL-tReeY8AHhPA7-nwvQKLqUEXQwTL4HhLXfZVre9jccpqQxFGIRYZH1ZQoAKCV5k1TGCLXXP9vMVsJFntDNz6Ozik02MANT1siBJRYTNIpGcj6p6Gbq5j0HvQChz7jtgdzwlj7nee0BdZphpg27ikQlVB5IUelMvSjzNNvPZawB9YbC9v6zyJngNQaJIJku2SPJkhFXIK0uoA;w=300;h=150;fg=000000;bg=f8f8f8");
var fileBytes = restClient.DownloadData(new RestRequest("#", Method.GET));
File.WriteAllBytes(Path.Combine(directory, "poster-got.jpg"), fileBytes);
```

The problem with this is that I only get an image that says "Media Error", Is there any way to get the image that is sent when you request the login page? Can it be done with restsharp? , if not with what library could I do it?

Comment: going to that url I see the image that says "media error".  this doesn't seem like an issue with RestSharp.  if you want to get a different image you'd have to call a different url

Comment: The solvemedia can only be printed 1 time, if I get the correct url I will still get half the error. When the HTTP request is sent to the page I need to download the image that is sent just then

Comment: I think that's why captcha's work the way they do, to prevent a non-human from being able to view it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For downloading image I use https://github.com/jgiacomini/Tiny.RestClient

But when I try to view your image in in my browser I have a media error. I think you use a wrong url.

In your case
    using Tiny.RestClient;

```
var client = new TinyRestClient(new HttpClient(), "@"http//api-secure.solvemedia.com");
FileInfo fileInfo = await client.
GetRequest("papi/media").
AddQueryParameter("2@gAB09NHSertXLv3TnpobmKDxvkjsaT4m@X4wLMdkN.u0ENU8bgrS3KH9APTC4lJjokJaIfZePPIgNLL84QkOaQlXcxzHvOVTTU98Of7mo8BoC0QQuiH1RMqMrGof6BbL-tReeY8AHhPA7-nwvQKLqUEXQwTL4HhLXfZVre9jccpqQxFGIRYZH1ZQoAKCV5k1TGCLXXP9vMVsJFntDNz6Ozik02MANT1siBJRYTNIpGcj6p6Gbq5j0HvQChz7jtgdzwlj7nee0BdZphpg27ikQlVB5IUelMvSjzNNvPZawB9YbC9v6zyJngNQaJIJku2SPJkhFXIK0uoA;w=300;h=150;fg=000000;bg=f8f8f8").
DownloadFileAsync("c:\"poster-got.jpg");
```